# Sending large string Ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been struggling with sending a large string to a PHP page via AJAX post method.The AJAX part seems to be working fine and sending the string without any problem,my problem is as soon as i redirect to my destination page the PHP $_POST seems to be empty.
I have made some research and i found out that this is a recurring problem but none of the solutions worked for me.

Ajax page [image: Ajax sending sing as intended]

PHP destination page

[image: PHP destination page]

AJAX code

```
$("#save").click(function(event){
var data = $("#mycontent").html();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "concat.php",
    cache:false,
    dataType:"html",
    data: {
        mycontent: data,
        },
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        top.location.href = 'concat.php';
    } 
});
});
```

PHP page

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['mycontent'])){
$content = $_POST['mycontent'];
}
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: There is a maximum size for POST requests in the PHP config. Make sure you did not hit that one.

Comment: Its in `php.ini` and it is called `post_max_size`

Comment: i have it set at 8M don't think that my string will ever go beyong 1M

post_max_size = 8M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $_POST vairable is not perserved between page redirection. You will need some other mechanism to perserve posted data ie. using $_GET, session or database etc.

Comment: where exactly did you spot a redirect?

Comment: How are you redirecting the page after the Ajax request? Mind posting the relevant code?

Comment: You are making the page redirect in your JS code `top.location.href = 'concat.php';` this basically send a GET request to /contact.php therefore POST data is not perserved

Comment: @Jason So this means that it sends to the destination page once and if i don't preserve it somehow it's gone !
Would you please explain to me more on how i can preserve my var via SESSION which seems my only solution at this point

Comment: @Jason is there any method to redirect to my destination without sending a GET

Comment: To store data in session use `$_SESSION['mydata'] = $_POST` . To retrieve the data from session `$_SESSION['mydata']`.

Comment: @Jason Shouldn't i refresh the page to get SESSION to store my string ( restart my php code to be able to catch that post ) ? wouldn't this get me to square one!

Comment: SESSION is perserved between pages so this won't be an issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120407/discussion-between-z3r0-and-jason).